# How to generate a four digit code (i.e 0001) javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to autogenerate a new four digit code that everytime I run the function the value increments. Such as 0001 the first time, 0002, 0003 and so on.
This is the code I have so far, the format is okay but I cant get it to increment the value automatically. I know it's probably a while loop but I wanted to ask advise on how it should be done. Thank you.

```
function pad(n){

var num = 1;
var string = "" + num;
var pad = "0000";
n = pad.substring(0, pad.length - string.length) + string;
num++;
return n;
}
```

Comment: you are defining your `num` inside the `pad` function, so every time you run `pad`, you will get a new `num` equal to `1`.  you should define `num` somewhere outside your function, or even better, supply the `num` as a parameter to the function.  You don't need to provide `n` as a parameter, since it is the return value of the function already.

Comment: Not a solution, but you might want to consider renaming the variable `string` as its a reserved word.

Comment: how to increment the number when the button is click ? i have tried it with a button but it won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>You should use [`left-pad`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad) for this</s> Joke aside you can avoid polluting the global scope with a closure:

```
var pad = (function(num) {
  return function() {
    var str = String(num++);
    while (str.length < 4) str = "0" + str;
    return str;
  }
})(1);
```

Usage:

```
console.log(pad()); // "0001"
console.log(pad()); // "0002"
console.log(pad()); // "0003"
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to keep the value of `num` outside function scope

otherwise, it will be `1` every time you invoke it

here is the solution:

```
var num = 1;

function pad(n){
    var string = "" + num;
    var pad = "0000";
    n = pad.substring(0, pad.length - string.length) + string;
    num++;
    return n;
}
```

also, to make it more reusable, you can do the following (which I think you intended to do):

```
var num = 1;

function pad(n){
    var string = "" + n;
    var pad = "0000";
    n = pad.substring(0, pad.length - string.length) + string;
    return n;
}

pad(num++); // 0001
pad(num++); // 0002
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString(locales, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).
In particular, its `minimumIntegerDigits` option makes you able to left-pad numbers to the required number of digits :

```
var number = 12;
number.toLocaleString(undefined, {useGrouping: false, minimumIntegerDigits: 4})
```

This will display `0012`.

Leaving the locales undefined tells the function to work with the OS's locale, which should always be ok since we switched off grouping and aren't displaying currencies nor decimal numbers.

`useGrouping` is the only option whose default doesn't work well with your need, if left unspecified it will instead display `0 012` for my locale (fr_FR) and probably `0,012` for the `en_US`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** I like [andlrc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647076/2542172). It's more JS way than my =)

===

better solution - without global variable (OOP style)

```
function ID(start){
  this.num = start || 0;
}

ID.prototype._to4DigitString = function(){
  return ("0000"+this.num).slice(-4);
}

ID.prototype.current = function(){
  return this._to4DigitString(this.num);
}

ID.prototype.next = function(){
  return this._to4DigitString(++this.num);
}

//then you can use it
var id = new ID();
id.next();    // "0001"
id.current(); // "0001"
id.next();    // "0002"
```

Comment: `("0000" + 12345).slice(-4)` gives `2345` instead of `12345`