# How to generate 4 digit Number from 0000 to 9999 using JS

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I want to print sequential number from 0000 to 9999.

This code just print 0000

```js
var pad = (function(num) {
  return function() {
    var str = String(num++);
    while (str.length < 4) str = "0" + str;
    return str;
  }
})(1);
```

from here [How to generate a four digit code (i.e 0001) javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647026/how-to-generate-a-four-digit-code-i-e-0001-javascript)

I did some changes but did't work with me:

```js
var j = 0;
for (j; j <= 9999; j++) {
  var pad = (function(num) {
    return function() {

      var str = String(num++);
      while (str.length < 4)
        str = "0" + str;
      return str;
    }
  })(0);
  console.log('Loop', j);
}
console.log('Number', pad());
```

Comment: Can you explain 'what's not working for me'?

Comment: You replaced the value of `pad` 10000 times, but only used `pad()` once.

Answer (score 0):

One liner using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const generatePaddedNums = (n) => Array.from(
  { length: n },
  (_, i) => i.toString().padStart((n - 1).toString().length, '0')
)
console.log(generatePaddedNums(10000))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the print pad() inside the loop and the function pad declared only once before the loop

```js
var j = 0;
var pad = (function(num) {
  return function() {
    var str = String(num++);
    while (str.length < 4) str = "0" + str;
    return str;
  }
})(1); 
for (j; j <= 9999; j++) {
  console.log('Number',pad())
  console.log('Loop', j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call pad() function inside for Loop

Refer below code

```
var pad = (function(num) {
    return function() {
        var str = String(
            num++);
        while (str.length <
            4)
            str = "0" + str;
        return str;
    }
})(1);

for (var i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    console.log('Number', pad());
}
```